# Symfony validation only on new form

Tags: php, symfony, validation

My validation works for creating a new entity, and not allowing a duplicate description.

How do I make this validation work for updating an entity, as it is, when updating the entity the validator is invoked and displays an error.

I'm still learning Symfony so please let me know any further details I need to provide.

descUnique.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class descUnique extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The description "{{ value }}" is allready in use.';
}
```

descUniqueValidator.php

```
class descUniqueValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    /**
     * @var Em
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        /* @var $constraint \App\Validator\descUnique */

        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        $repo = $this->em->getRepository(Carrier::class)
                ->findUniqueName($this->security->getUser(), $value);

        
        if ($repo) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $value)
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }

}
```

**edit**

My validator declaration in the entity object.

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Validator\CarrierDescUnique
     */
    private $description;
```

Comment: Is `$value` in your validator a Carrier-entity? If so, depending on how this class looks, you could check for the id. So, basically `if ($repo && $repo->getId() !== $value->getId())` This assumes, that `getId()` will work even if you don't have an id set, for example it will return null instead of an integer.

Comment: I've updated my question. Is there a way to pass an entity to the validator? My validator just passes the value from the form not the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

What is the displayed error?

Without the error message the only thing I can see that could go wrong is that you don't check the type of `Constraint` inside the validate method. Could it be that another constraint is being tested in this validator by accident?

Also, the type of `$value` is not checked. That might cause some problems in case `$value` is neither `''`, `null` nor a string (i assumed a string is correct in your case).

Comment: There is no error, the problem is it always tries to validate, I'm trying to find a way the validation doesn't run during an update.

Comment: Ok, maybe I understood the question wrong. As far as I undestand now - you want to validate on create only? And not to validate an already created entity? 

In this case you need to apply a constraint to the whole class instead of just one attribute, and inside the validator have something that checks whether the entity is new (created_at is null / id is null etc. depends on your app).

There is an example of how to appy a constraint to a class at the bottom of this article: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thanks for that, I found https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path a lot more helpful.